# Database server for Android apps

Tags: android

I am actually learning to develop a Mobile Application like Supply Chain management system which would be used by different users . It has to communicate with database. I first thought of using SQLlite but then realized this would be maintained in the mobile but i am looking like a server where I can manage the database. I did some google and looked in this site too it has mentioned to use web services or http handlers. I see many experienced people in this blog hence thought could ask my question here.

Which is the best way or a server to handle this and is there any link where I could learn and implement the same. I would really appreicate some response on this. I think I am clear in my question.

Comment: is it your own database? Please provide more about information about the database,

Comment: Yes it should be my database server something like SQL? What are the steps or how should I go on this.. How would I maintain the database from my side also when the mobile user  makes changes it should be reflected in my server both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some RESTful web services to access the database, then the Android app can call the web services to get data from the db or post data to the db using XML or JSON as the format of data.

check out some stuff on [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/)  and one tutorial [Building RESTful Web Services with Jersey](http://matthewturland.com/slides/jersey/)